# Kernel and image of map on unit group of finite field

Tags: linear-algebra, ring-theory, field-theory, finite-fields

This question is from a rings and modules course I'm doing:

Let $p>2$ be prime and $f:\mathbb{F}_{p}^{*}\rightarrow \mathbb{F}_{p}^{*}$ be given by $x \mapsto x^\frac{p-1}{2}$. Prove that $ker(f)$ has at most $\frac{p-1}{2}$ elements and $im(f)=\left \{ \pm1 \right \}$.

Attempt: Let $\mathbb{F}_{p}^{*}={1,x_{1},y_{1},...,x_{n},y_{n}}$ where $x_{i}y_{i}=1$

$x_{i} \in ker(f) \Rightarrow x_{i}^\frac{p-1}{2}=1$
Therefore $(x_{i}y_{i})^\frac{p-1}{2}=1^\frac{p-1}{2} \Rightarrow x_{i}^\frac{p-1}{2}y_{i}^\frac{p-1}{2}=1 \Rightarrow y_{i}^\frac{p-1}{2}=1 \Rightarrow y_{i} \in Ker(f)$

This is as far as I've got since it seems to say that if $\mathbb{F}_{p}^{*}=\mathbb{F}_{p}\backslash\left \{ 0 \right \}$ then $ker(f)$ can be as large as $p-1$?

I had assumed that what I wanted to prove was that if $x_{i} \in ker(f)$ then $y_{i} \notin ker(f)$ but that doesn't seem to work?

Thanks in advance for your help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hints:

$$\begin{align*}(1)&\;\;\forall x\in\Bbb F_p^*\;,\;\;x^{p-1}=1\\
(2)&\;\;\text{For}\;\;x\in\Bbb F_p^*\;,\;\;x^2=1\iff x=\pm 1\\(3)&\;\;\forall\,n\in\Bbb N\;,\;\;\text{a polynomial of degree $\,n\,$ over}\;\;\Bbb F_p^n\;\;\text{has at most $\,n\,$ different roots}\end{align*}$$

Comment: So, if we assume $ker(f)=\mathbb{F}_{p}^{*}$ then $x_{i}^\frac{p-1}{2}y_{i}^\frac{p-1}{2}=1=x_{i}^{p-1} \Rightarrow y_{i}^\frac{p-1}{2}=x_{i}^\frac{p-1}{2} \Rightarrow y_{i}=x_{i}$ and so $\mathbb{F}_{p}^{*}$ only has $\frac{p-1}{2}$ elements and so does $ker(f)$?

Comment: Why would you assume such thing there at the beginning?! That'd mean the map is trivial!

Comment: Wouldn't the maximum size of $ker(f)$ be the size of its domain?

Comment: Yes...so?? I really don't see your point.

Comment: So, I was assuming that to find the largest number of elements $ker(f)$ can contain, we assume that it's equal to its domain and then see where that leads?

Comment: If you *really* assume $\;\ker f=\Bbb F_p^*\;$ then the map is the trivial map: **all** the elements are mapped to $\;1\;$ ...! Do you *really* want to assume this? And if you do, how does this help you to solve the question?!

Comment: Ah, okay. So (ignoring earlier assumption...) $(1) \Rightarrow (x^\frac{p-1}{2})^{2}=1 \Rightarrow x^\frac{p-1}{2}=\pm 1$ since $xy=1 \Rightarrow x^\frac{p-1}{2}y^\frac{p-1}{2}=1 \Rightarrow x^\frac{p-1}{2} \in \mathbb{F}_{p}^{*}$ then $(3) \Rightarrow x^\frac{p-1}{2}=1$ has at most $\frac{p-1}{2}$ distinct roots, so $ker(f)$ has at most $\frac{p-1}{2}$ elements?